# Laravel 5 get random post

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, random, laravel-5

There is a link "Get Random Story" `<a href="#" class="btn-get-random-post">Get Random Story</a>` on the main page of my site, on click I need to get random post from DB and show it on the same window.
I use Laravel 5.4.

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{

public function index() {
    return redirect('/');
}

public function show($id) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}

public function getRandomPost() {
    $post = Post::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
}
```

routes

```
Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::post('posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::post('publish', 'PostsController@publish');
Route::post('delete', 'PostsController@delete');
Route::post('get-random-post', 'PostsController@getRandomPost');
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.btn-get-random-post').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './get-random-post',               
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

And I have 2 problems here
1. Method `getRandomPost()` returns post, but how to display it? I want to get as result page with url `mysite/post/{id}` like url from method `show`.
2. Is there any way to get and display random post (with url `mysite/post/{id}`) without AJAX?

**UPD**
Controller

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{


public function index() {
    return redirect('/');
}

public function show($id) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}

public function getRandomPost() {
    $post = Post::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
}
}
```

link on the main page 
`<a href="{{ action('PostsController@getRandomPost') }}">Random Story</a>`

routes

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::post('posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::post('publish', 'PostsController@publish');
Route::post('delete', 'PostsController@delete');
Route::post('get-random-post', 'PostsController@getRandomPost');
Route::post('dashboard/delete', 'PostsController@delete');
Route::post('dashboard/unpublish', 'PostsController@unpublish');
Route::post('dashboard/restore', 'PostsController@restore');
```

error
[image]

Comment: the method not allowed error usually refers to the case when you are using an invalid method on a controller, like calling a get method with post. As seeing your route definitions, this is the case. change the get-random-post to GET

Answer (score 1):

sure, instead if returning a view in the `getRandomPost`
return a redirect response to the route

But first,

You don't seem to have assigned names to your routes.

change `Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show');`
to `Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');`

Also, you might want to assign a name to your random-post route too, you you can generate urls in views for it

this way you will be able to generate routes for it.

`return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);`

After all this, you can just use the route on a link, or redirect the page after a button click to the route: `get-random-post`

No ajax needed.

Comment: This won't work because he is loading the response using ajax

Comment: that is what he wants to avoid (AJAX)

Comment: I've tried to use your answer, but in this case I get an error and redirect doesn't work ( I updated my question and added code and screenshot). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the method not allowed error usually refers to the case when you are using an invalid method on a controller, like calling a get method with post.

As seeing your route definitions, this is the case. change the `get-random-post` to GET

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid the javascript altogether by changing the url to `mysite/post`. If there is an id, route to show, if not, route to the `getRandomPost()` method.

Comment: that problem with that is in that case the url would just stay `mysite/get-random-post`; a redirect is a must

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment as a reply to your answer. Was adding on to what you originally said.